# Load more items doesn't appear (Vue JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm figure out how the load more feature works in vue.js. I have data, at the beginning I want to display 2 data. If I click the load more button, it will display 1 data and so on. When the all data already loaded, the button will disappear. And I have a filter feature. When the filtered item contains only 1 data, the load more button will not appear, but when the filter data is more than 2, the load more button will appear.

I have made the code as below, but the item doesn't appear. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    selectedCountry: '',
    selectedYear: '',
    items: [{
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'belgium'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england'
      }
    ],
    searchResult: [],
    commentsToShow: 2,
    totalComments: 0
  },
  methods: {
    search: function() {
      let filterType = this.selectedType,
        filterCountry = this.selectedCountry,
        filterYear = this.selectedYear

      this.searchResult = this.items.filter(function(item) {
        let filtered = true
        if (filterType && filterType.length > 0) {
          filtered = item.type == filterType
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterCountry && filterCountry.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.country == filterCountry
          }
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterYear && filterYear.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.year == filterYear
          }
        }
        return filtered
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.search()
    this.totalComments = this.reviews.length
    console.log(this.reviews.length)
  }
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.1/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedType">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  </select>

  <select v-model="selectedCountry">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Country</option>
    <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="england">England</option>
  </select>

  <select v-model="selectedYear">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
  </select>

  <button @click="search">Search</button>

  <div class="list-item" v-if="item < items.length" v-for="item in searchResult">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
      <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
      <p>Year: {{ item.year }}</p>
      <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div v-if="commentsToShow < items.length">
    <button @click="commentsToShow += 1">Load More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issue with your condition in v-if directives. i have made the changes and the output is as described by you.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <select v-model="selectedType">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
        </select>

        <select v-model="selectedCountry">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Country</option>
            <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
            <option value="england">England</option>
        </select>

        <select v-model="selectedYear">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>

        <button @click="search">Search</button>

        <div class="list-item" v-for="(item, id) in searchResult" :key="id">
            <div v-if="id < commentsToShow"> //Changes
                <div class="card">
                    <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
                    <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
                    <p>Year: {{ item.year }}</p>
                    <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="commentsToShow < searchResult.length"> //Changes
            <button @click="commentsToShow += 1">Load More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    selectedCountry: '',
    selectedYear: '',
    items: [{
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'belgium'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england'
      }
    ],
    searchResult: [],
    commentsToShow: 2,
    totalComments: 0
  },
  methods: {
    search: function() {
      let filterType = this.selectedType,
        filterCountry = this.selectedCountry,
        filterYear = this.selectedYear

    this.commentsToShow = 2; //Changes

      this.searchResult = this.items.filter(function(item) {
        let filtered = true
        if (filterType && filterType.length > 0) {
          filtered = item.type == filterType
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterCountry && filterCountry.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.country == filterCountry
          }
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterYear && filterYear.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.year == filterYear
          }
        }
        return filtered
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.search()
    // this.totalComments = this.reviews.length
    // console.log(this.reviews.length)
  }
})
```

I have added this.commentsToShow in search function because every time you search something you need re-initialize this variable because by default you want to show only 2 cards.

Comment: binding key id ?

Comment: @Frauds it is a best practice to use with v-for directive... and binding key is use for indexing the loop position